# Does anyone know of to calculate the GTI VERA Convergence and Divergence Indicator?

Tags: trading, technical-analysis

I came across this indicator - GTI VERA Convergence and Divergence Indicator through this URL - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVl6o45dytEX0h5Ml9HQTNvT1k/view

I can't seem to find how this is indicator is arrived at.

Thank you.

Comment: The link is broken, which makes this question difficult to understand.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that I have no clue how this indicator is calculated.

Don't get mesmerized by the cherry picked examples that sites like this one offer.  Any indicator that involves moving averages is a lagging indicator.  That means late in and late out, working well in trending markets and offering lots of whipsaws in non trending markets  which are conveniently ignored (see the charts in your link).

If you find the formula, back test some data. I bet that the performance will be spotty, at best.

Answer (score -1):

I am glad you encounter our technical indicators, they are published at Bloomberg terminal and as you mentioned the document is a user guide with the basic functions and a brief explanation of the theory behind it. We can not disclose the complete formula.

Comment: Welcome to Personal Finance & Money! [Answers on StackExchange are supposed to be self-contained](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) so asking someone to email you doesn't fit here. I have left the part of your answer that makes it clear you are not willing to disclose the formula.